# Creating Extension Delegate class for Watch OS2

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I recently upgraded my existing watch OS app to watch OS 2. I noticed there was no Extension Delegate class so I tried creating it myself.

Here are the steps I've taken.

Created a Swift file called ExtensionDelegate.swift

```
    import WatchKit

class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate{
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
        NSLog("test");
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive() {


    }



    func applicationWillResignActive() {


    }
}
```

I added the following to my Watchkit extension Info.plist
"WKExtensionDelegateClassName" with a value of "ExtensionDelegate"

However, I cannot hit the breakpoint in my applicationDidFinishLaunching() delegate method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I had to use the following value for WKExtensionDelegateClassName

$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate